# Where does the stderr from launchd go?

Tags: macos, launchd

`launchd` items in /Library/LaunchDaemon may redirect stdin/stdout/stderr. E.g. I've got an item that says:

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Library/Logs/rnamanagedocker_out.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath></key>
    <string>/Library/Logs/rnamanagedocker_err.log</string>
```

I do get the `stdout` in `/Library/Logs/rnamanagedocker_out.log`, but no `/Library/Logs/rnamanagedocker_err.log` is created while I am certain there is `stderr` output.

Any tips?

[UPDATE Jan 17] I have now noticed that I do get stderr in an expected output file. Either I was mistaken or there was some setup I cannot reproduce that got the stderr output lost. Probably the first (picnic, problem in chair, not in computer).

Answer (score 5):

Your second key has a typo in it (has a `>` before the closing `</key>`)

```
                      *
<key>StandardErrorPath></key>
    <string>/Library/Logs/rnamanagedocker_err.log</string>
```

It should be

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Library/Logs/rnamanagedocker_err.log</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try making sure that the system is actually permitted to write to that file. I would suggest simply creating the file in advance (as an empty file). You can do that with the Terminal as follows:

```
touch /Library/Logs/rnamanagedocker_err.log
```

Then try first by making the file writable by everyone to see, if that makes it work:

```
chmod a+w /Library/Logs/rnamanagedocker_err.log
```

If you want then you can then start limited the permissions on the file to get to the level you require.

Comment: Actually, this was not expected to help, because if you can write the out file in the same directory, why not the err file? But I tried anyway, and it did not help.

Comment: I don't know why you had those expectations, but if one file already exists and is writable - it would be logical why you could write to that file, but not the other one.

Comment: I had that expectation because the other file was also created on the first write. I never created it by hand. But agreed, error could behave differently.

Comment: You didn't write that in your question, so I couldn't know that when I answered. How have you checked that something is actually output to stderr?

Comment: By running the command by hand.

Comment: And how did you check that something was actually output to stderr when you ran the command by hand?

Comment: Redirecting stderr in a shell would do the trick. Or having written the program in the first place and knowing that some stuff is going to stderr. But I am going to update this one as I have now found actual stderr output and I'm at a loss to find the configuration where I did not see it.

Comment: I’m well aware of how to do it. I was asking you did it in order to ascertain whether the problem could be that the output really wasn’t sent to stderr, but rather to stdout instead. If you feel that you know in advance that our suggestions are not helpful, then that’s OK too - but a bit of a waste of time.